# Raising ActiveRecord::Rollback and loosing nested attribute values as a result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In general I am trying to batch validate a bunch of objects and I need to save them to execute the uniqueness validations. Then I am rolling back the objects that needed to be saved for the uniqueness validation.

This is needed for a batch importing UI where I want to notify users about problems in their data before they have the option to persist the data.

The approach seems to fail because the object is losing its nested attributes when it is saved for the second time. So when saving the object a second time, MySQL/SQlite will rightfully tell me about the column being null.

Here is an example:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :posts, force: true do |t|
    t.string :title
  end

  create_table :comments, force: true do |t|
    t.text :body, null: false
    t.integer :post_id
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

posts = [Post.new(title: "Title", comments_attributes: [{ body: "Comment" }])]

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  posts.each do |p|
    p.save # This saves fine
    # Collecting validation errors here for presentation purposes
  end
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end

# Now the comment attributes seem to be gone and
# Mysql is raising an error because the 'body' column is null
posts.each { |p| p.save }
```

I have a fully runnable testcase here: https://gist.github.com/phansch/ab172e4b8cadf24f1e6508a0555e465c

Is there some way around this? I guess my problem boils down to having to execute the uniqueness validations to tell the user about duplicates before the user decides to go ahead and really persist the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save and then rollback the Post records to validate uniqueness. You can directly call `post.valid?`, and all validations (including uniqueness validations) will be run.

Instead of

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  posts.each do |p|
    p.save # This saves fine
    # Collecting validation errors here for presentation purposes
  end
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

Just do

```
posts.each(&:valid?)
```

I just tested it, and it looks like the nested records are unaffected by this approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, the uniqueness validation will only compare the new record with the ones that have already been persisted. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness. So when I have an array of two unsaved posts that have the same title it would not tell me, since none of them are persisted.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Individual validations are contingent on the rest of the collection. That makes this a bit harder. :/ AR only supports single row inserts... The only good option I see is to write some custom checks, outside of AR, to check the entire posts array. The only thing to check here is that all the titles are unique before running posts.each(&:valid?). In any case, I would discourage validation via AR transaction. If you're feeling adventurous, you could also check out some mass importing gems like activerecord-import and see if they support something like this.